# What to use in place of Analog Clock in Android Studio as it's been Deprecated in API 23?

Tags: android, android-studio, clock

I am new to Android Development and I saw analog clock in Design View but when I add it through java it says Analog Clock is Deprecated in API 23. So my question is what I can use in place of that.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a replacement. What exactly do you need it for?

Comment: I just needed this to make my UI look better

Comment: Why display a clock at all in your app? You can do what you want of course, but it's a bit unusual. You might just have to build your own clock View.

Answer (score 0):

There are different libraries that do this. I have used :  https://github.com/rosenpin/custom-analog-clock-view

```
    clockView = (CustomAnalogClock) view.findViewById(R.id.analog_clock);
    clockView.setScale(0.2f);  //set size 
    clockView.setTime(Calendar.getInstance()); //setTime
```

Comment: Be warned - the linked library is GPL3, not safe for commercial work